# generated ng-click does not send variables

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

Have a problem with a generated ng-click event.

Basically, I generate the following code:

```
<button class="padbtn" data-ng-click="playBeat({sndType: smpBeat, sndId:C0})">
    <img class="padImg" src="/api/getImg/554240a17b221e1a2ffda097" style="width:175px; height 175px;"/>
    <br/>
    Boat
</button>
```

This is then compiled and added to a div. 
There is (in the same controller) a function called playBeat:

```
$scope.playBeat = function (sndType, sndId){                
    console.log('Was asked to play '+ sndId);               
}
```

It gets called, but for some reason it does not receive the sndType or sndId, and in both cases it comes back with

> BabyDevel.js:134 Was asked to play undefined

Not really certain what to make of this issue, or even where I can debug it, quite certain it is sending the options though.

== UPDATE ==
I also tried

```
<button class="padbtn" data-ng-click="playBeat(smpBeat,C0)"><img class="padImg" src="/api/getImg/554240a17b221e1a2ffda097" style="width:175px; height 175px;"/><br/>Boat</button>
```

Without the JSON, but that had the same effect.

Comment: remove your curly brackets {}

Comment: don't send your parameters as json.Send as separate parameters

    playBeat(smpBeat,C0)
your method doesn't accept json object,accept separate variables

Comment: You're calling playBeat with a single object having two properties. Not surprising printing the second argument prints undefined, since the function is called using 1 argument.

Comment: I tried that at first, same effect (have added second version above). I changed it to json because there was another comment on here that mentioned that that was the way to do it.

Comment: Then it means that `C0` is undefined. Do you have a `C0` attribute in the scope? Why don't you post your code?

Comment: I am an idiot. Thanks JB Nizet, I lost track of how many wrappings I needed, I had forgotten that I needed to wrap the code to the compiler so that it sent C0 as a string not a value, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The correct use would be

```
data-ng-click="playBeat(smpBeat, C0)"
```